# What is the problem of this simple #define C code?

Tags: c

Here's the example code.

```
#define A 100
#define B A+1
```

I've been reading C basic books and the writer said that code could cause fatal problems and there is no explanation about it.

why this code has a problem? I want to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you try to write:

```
int foo = B * 10;
```

You probably expect this to set `B` to `1010`. But it will actually set it to `110` because it expands to

```
int foo = 100+1 * 10;
```

Because of operator precedence, the multiplication is done first, so it's `100 + 10`, not `101 * 10`.

To prevent problems like this, you should put parentheses around the macro expansion.

```
#define B (A+1)
```

Then it will expand to

```
int foo = (100+1) * 10;
```

and you'll get the expected result.